# Bifurcation Analysis and Lyapunov Exponents Visualization

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, nonlinear

```
(*Define the model equations*)
modelEquations[{x_, y_}, {a_, k_, b_, d_, p_, c_, e_, 
   f_}] := {x Exp[
    a (1 - x/k) - (b (1 - p) y)/(1 + c (1 - p) x + d y)], 
  y Exp[((e b (1 - p) x)/(1 + c (1 - p) x + d y)) - f]}

(*Compute the Jacobian matrix*)
jacobian[{x_, y_}, params_] := 
 D[modelEquations[{x, y}, params], {{x, y}}]

(*Initialize parameters and ranges*)
params = {a, k, b, d, p, c, e, f};
initialConditions = {2.6, 2.7};
paramValues = {3.2, 1.8, 0.2, 0.2, 0.9, 2.9};  (*b,d,p,c,e,f*)
aRange = Range[0.1, 10, 0.1];
kRange = Range[0.1, 10, 0.1];

(*Simulation and bifurcation analysis*)
bifurcationAnalysis = 
  Flatten[Table[{a, k, 
     LyapunovExponents = 
      Re[Mean[Log[
         Abs[Eigenvalues[
           jacobian[initialConditions, {a, k}~Join~paramValues]]]]]], 
     BifurcationType = 
      Which[And @@ (LyapunovExponents < 0), "Stable Node", 
       And @@ (LyapunovExponents > 0), "Unstable Node", True, 
       "Saddle Point"]}, {a, aRange}, {k, kRange}], 1];

(*Visualization*)
ListContourPlot[bifurcationAnalysis[[All, {1, 2, 3}]], 
 FrameLabel -> {"a", "k"}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, Contours -> 20, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLabel -> "Bifurcation Diagram with Lyapunov Exponents"]
```

I don't understand how to fix this error
[image]

Comment: The error is from the `D` in `D[modelEquations[{x, y}, params], {{x, y}}]`. `{x,y}` is passed in as `initialConditions`, which is `{2.6, 2.7}`.

Comment: Change your definition from: `D[modelEquations[{x0, y0}, params], {{x0, y0}}] /. {x0 -> x, y0 -> y}`  to `D[modelEquations[{x0, y0}, params], {{x0, y0}}] /. {x0 -> x, y0 -> y}`

Comment: Not necessarily a Mathematica comment, but could you explain what you're calculating?  Usually calculating Lyapunov exponents requires iterating the model on the attractor, but I don't see that here.  (could be I just don't follow the code well)

Comment: @ChrisK the method used in the code is a shortcut that leverages the Jacobian matrix to approximate Lyapunov exponents locally rather than iterating the full dynamical system over time. This approach can be useful for a bifurcation analysis but does not replace the full Lyapunov exponent calculation for understanding the global dynamical behavior.

Comment: @AthanasiosParaskevopoulos Interesting, could you give a reference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To solve this problem it could be better to define system of equations and Jacobian as expressions in a form of

```
(*Define the model equations*)
modelEquations = {x Exp[
     a (1 - x/k) - (b (1 - p) y)/(1 + c (1 - p) x + d y)], 
   y Exp[((e b (1 - p) x)/(1 + c (1 - p) x + d y)) - f]};

(*Compute the Jacobian matrix*)
jacobian = D[modelEquations, {{x, y}}];
```

With these definitions we have

```
(*Initialize parameters and ranges*)
params = {a, k, b, d, p, c, e, f};
initialConditions = {2.6, 2.7};
paramValues = {3.2, 1.8, 0.2, 0.2, 0.9, 2.9};  (*b,d,p,c,e,f*)
aRange = Range[0.1, 10, 0.1];
kRange = Range[0.1, 10, 0.1];

(*Simulation and bifurcation analysis*)
bifurcationAnalysis = 
  Flatten[Table[{a1, k1, 
     LyapunovExponents = 
      Re[Mean[Log[
         Abs[Eigenvalues[
           jacobian /. 
             Thread[params -> Join[{a1, k1}, paramValues]] /. 
            Thread[{x, y} -> initialConditions]]]]]], 
     BifurcationType = 
      Which[And @@ (LyapunovExponents < 0), "Stable Node", 
       And @@ (LyapunovExponents > 0), "Unstable Node", True, 
       "Saddle Point"]}, {a1, .05, 10, 0.05}, {k1, 0.05, 10, .05}], 
   1];
```

Visualization

```
ListContourPlot[bifurcationAnalysis[[All, 1 ;; 3]], 
 FrameLabel -> {"a", "k"}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, Contours -> 20, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotRange -> Automatic, 
 PlotLabel -> "Bifurcation Diagram with Lyapunov Exponents"]
```

[image: Figure 1]